# Best way to search for a string in a file on a network drive

Tags: windows, perl, vbscript

Here is my problem: We have a file server (Windows 2003) that people keep putting forms on that contain PII. Policy is now that the last 4 of a person's SSN is no longer allowed on any forms on our file servers. I'm trying to figure out a script to scan for a string such as "SSN" or "Last Four" in a document and all I can find are instructions/examples on how to search text files on a local machine. I have seen a lot of threads similar to this but primarily searching a txt file in a local folder. I've seen powershell scripts that do this but (don't ask why) powershell scripting is disabled on our servers.

Is this possible? I've been reading heavily into multiple Perl books to hope for a clue or get me in the right direction and have had 0 luck.

Comment: The *best* way is to run a script on the server.  Network access is slow.

Comment: Thank you josh3736...I was thinking that but that does help with part of my problem.

Comment: Are you talking all sorts of different forms (file types) or is the file type consistent?

Comment: all sorts of different forms. PDF, Doc, Docx, xls etc which is something that i'm not good enough with perl to know if it can search those or strictly txt, csv, etc type files.

Comment: @Fosterocalypse: It can, if you define normalization subroutines to get them into a consistent state before running your search code. I'm curious -- why aren't you just using Windows Search? Given a reasonably up-to-date version of Windows it can search file contents for phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get access to the files eventually, here's how you can go about searching a directory of files, looking for a string match.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

our $CHECK_FILE_EXTENSION = qr/.txt$/;
File::Find::find({wanted=>\&find_ssn, no_chdir=>1},$_) for @ARGV;
exit;

sub find_ssn
{
    ## File::Find sets $File::Find::name with full path to file, which is the correct path to an 'open' call when 'no_chdir' is used
    return unless $File::Find::name =~ $CHECK_FILE_EXTENSION;
    open F,$File::Find::name || die "Can't read file, $File::Find::name, $!\n";
    while(<F>)
    {
        if(/SSN/)
        {   
           ## file as 'SSN' in it, do your work here
        }
    }
    close F;
}
```

Comment: i'm pretty green when it comes to this ...but the line "## file as 'SSN' in it, do your work here" do you mean this would be where I would put for example to copy the filename to a text log file?

Comment: Correct.  That "## file as SSN" is basically where you are at in a file and you've found SSN -- at this point you could, for example, log to another file and then use 'last' to stop looping over lines in that file and move on to the next file

Comment: The diff between Oesor's solution and mine is that I only read one line at a time, whereas File::Slurp reads the entire file into memory before doing a search...so you'll have to decide what's a good approach to you.  The tricky part of Oesor's solution is that the string to search has newlines in it and the regex doesn't use /s (for single-line match, ie dont let newlines stop search)

Comment: Thanks to mrk & Oesor for your help..I haven't completly solved my problem but with your guys help i feel like i'm making progress.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from i/o speed, there's no real difference in accessing a file remotely vs locally. It's just a file descriptor.

```
C:\>perl -MFile::Slurp -E "my $dir = q|//SERVER/Share/Test|; for my $file (read_dir($dir)) { say qq|$file: |, (read_file(qq|$dir/$file|) =~ /foo/) ? q|match| : q|not match| }"
bar.txt: not match
foo.txt: match
```